# Tags in OpenStreetMap

Tags: postgresql, tags, openstreetmap

I have been trying to convert .osm files to shapefiles using osm2pgsql with no luck. I have eventually found the necessary shapefiles on http://downloads.cloudmade.com. I am now trying to view source tags in OSM. I have downloaded the shapefiles and have loaded them into Postgres. When I view the data, I am unable to see any tagging data. Should I be following a different process or using shapefiles at all?

Comment: I have used Postgis shapefile loader in pgAdminIII to load files into Postgres.

Comment: I eventually imported the files into Postgres using osm2pgsql. It seems that some data does not get imported if simply using shapefiles.

Comment: could you define a little more clearly what exactly you are trying to find that you can't see?

Answer (score 0):

By my reading of the documentation, as of March, 2013, importing tagging data is not supported by this tool.  Maybe it will be supported in the future but it isn't in the present.